# Problems with using the result from an external python function

Tags: python, pythontex

I am trying to implement a python function (which processes text for me) in my tex document. Thus I started as following:
Tex:

```
%& -shell-escape
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pythontex}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\newcommand{\printPython}[1]{
\pyc{print(r'Hello #1')}%
}
\begin{document}

Say hello Python:

%\begin{python}%
%print r"Hello \LaTeX!"
%\end{python}%
\printPython{Test}

\begin{pycode}
from BigLet import *

a = modifyText("Hallo Welt")
print(r"\textit{\py{modifyText("HalloWelt")}}")
print(r"\newline")
print(r"\centering")
print(r"\textit{A message from Python!}")
\end{pycode}

\end{document}
```

`BigLet.py`:

```
from __future__ import division

def modifyText(inputstring):
    wordlist = inputstring.split(' ')
    chordItem = '\\'
    if chordItem not in wordlist[0]:
        firstWord = wordlist[0]
        firstLetter = firstWord[0]
        modWord = "\lettrine{"+firstLetter+"}{"+firstWord[1:]+'}'
        fullText = modWord + ' ' + inputstring[len(firstWord):]
        return fullText
    else:
        firstWord = wordlist[1]
        print firstWord
        firstLetter = firstWord[0]
        modWord = "\lettrine{"+firstLetter+"}{"+firstWord[1:]+'}'
        fullText = inputstring[:len(wordlist[0])] + ' ' + modWord + ' ' + inputstring[len(wordlist[0]) + len(firstWord):]
        return fullText
```

My problem is now that I can neither access the value of `a` (which is a string) nor use the line `print(r"\textit{\py{modifyText("HalloWelt")}}")`. When using the line, I get the error

```
print(r"\textit{\py{modifyText("HalloWelt")}}")
                                              ^
  SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

When I am printing `a` by using `print(r"\textit{a}")`, I just get the letter `a`. When changing that line into `print(r"\textit{\py{a}}")`, I get two question marks. How can I access the resulting string from the external function, and pass it forward? Just printing works.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`print(r"\textit{\py{modifyText("HalloWelt")}}")` is giving a syntax error because you are trying to include unescaped literal double quotes within a double quote-delimited string. You would need something like `print(r'\textit{\py{modifyText("HalloWelt")}}')`

`print(r"\textit{a}")` is printing a string, so you just get the string.

You probably want something like `print(r"\textit{" + a + "}")` or perhaps `print(r"\textit{{{a}}}".format(a=a))`.  Or you could avoid the temporary variable and use `print(r"\textit{" + modifyText("Hallo Welt") + "}")`  There are almost no situations in which printing `\py{...}` is actually necessary. Typically, you can just assemble the final text, and then print that.

If you get two question marks, that is an indication that you need to run PythonTeX again, and then recompile.